# NFS mount within K8s pods failing

Tags: kubernetes, mount, nfs

I am trying to get NFS share mounted into a k8s pod but its failing with the below error

mount.nfs: rpc.statd is not running but is required for remote locking. mount.nfs: Either use '-o nolock' to keep locks local, or start statd.

I tried to start rpcbind using CMD command in docker container that also did not work.

My deployment yaml is as below

```
kind: Deployment
apiVersion: apps/v1
metadata:
  name: nfs-client-provisioner
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nfs-client-provisioner
  replicas: 1
  strategy:
    type: Recreate
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nfs-client-provisioner
    spec:
      serviceAccountName: nfs-client-provisioner
      containers:
        - name: nfs-client-provisioner
          image: gcr.io/k8s-staging-sig-storage/nfs-subdir-external-provisioner:v4.0.0
          volumeMounts:
            - name: nfs-client-root
              mountPath: /persistentvolumes
          env:
            - name: PROVISIONER_NAME
              value: nfs-provisioner
            - name: NFS_SERVER
              value: NFS SERVER PATH
            - name: NFS_PATH
              value: /filesharepath
      volumes:
        - name: nfs-client-root
          nfs:
            server: <NFS IP>
            path: /filesharepath
```

I saw in github that there is an identical issue which says rpcbind needs to be on the base system.

https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/nfs-subdir-external-provisioner/issues/224

Please assist.

Comment: i can help you since im using it but just curious, be sure to create the pv with that storage class as default

Comment: The above deployment itself fails, so I am unable to create the storage class mentioning the above provisioner.